# Using Google drive API to upload files in G-Drive facing issue

Tags: node.js, api, google-drive-api, drive

*Hi,
Using Google Drive API to upload files in the Drive.
The file gets uploaded successfully but in response, the file ID is showing undefined.
I have to use the file id for further code *

```
function uplodeFile(auth){
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'error.jpg'
      };
      var media = {
        mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
        body: fs.createReadStream('Capture.JPG')
      };
      drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: 'id'
      }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
        }
      });
}
```

[This is the Snippet of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqxNY.png)

Comment: I thought that this question might be the duplicate. But I couldn't find the duplicated question. So I answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of googleapis for Node.js, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
```

#### To:

```
console.log('File Id: ', file.data.id);
```

- In the current stage, the latest version is `v61.0.0`.

#### Reference:

- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)